# WP site certain url redirecting to external URL in WP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

In My WP site Recently i found out two URl http://www.nepaljapan.com/buy-cialis-in-the-uk/ and  http://nepaljapan.com/buy-cialis-in-the-uk/  whose page and post or nothing is available in back-end of WP and when i entered this URL in browser it redirects into new site now google sending us message as spam  or malware or hacked due to this URL so can you guys help me out how to remove this URL

Answer (score 0):

This is more than likely because some of your source files have been compromised and although these pages don't exist in the database, the redirect is being initiated from source.

You could try the tips listed here to see if you can clean up the source files to remove any potential malware:

https://sucuri.net/guides/how-to-clean-hacked-wordpress

If you're not technical yourself, I have used Sucuri's services in the past as they can do this stuff for you and get your site back to normal (there is a fee for this though).

Also, if you have an earlier backup of your source files, it's worth trying to revert to those to see if that fixes the issue.